# Trouble with quotes in ant's <exec>

Tags: linux, ant, ubuntu-12.04

This is the command that runs just fine on terminal

```
egrep Version ./path/fileName.java | cut -d"\"" -f4
```

I've used the following in my code

```
<exec command="egrep Version ./path/fileName.java | cut -d&quot;\&quot; -f4)" outputproperty="VER"/>
```

But getting errors

```
the command attribute is deprecated.
 [exec] Please use the executable attribute and nested arg elements.
 [exec] Result: 1
 [echo] "Version: egrep: invalid argument `\\' for `--directories'
 [echo] Valid arguments are:
 [echo]   - `read'
 [echo]   - `recurse'
 [echo]   - `skip'
 [echo] Usage: egrep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
 [echo] Try `egrep --help' for more information."
```

there is one less quot; in the command because if I write 2 quots, it will give me number of quots unbalanced error.

Comment: I guess this is Ant? XML is not a programming language. Ant is (well, a scripting language, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant's `<exec>` uses Java's rules for execution, in particular it is *not* a shell and does not understand pipes and redirections on its own. Probably your best bet will be to invoke a shell. You will also need to capture the output in a property if you want to make use of it later in your build:

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="version.number">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="egrep Version ./path/fileName.java | cut -d'&quot;' -f4" />
</exec>
```

Alternatively, you could forget the exec and implement the required logic directly in Ant using [loadfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) with a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) rather than calling an external process:

```
<loadfile srcFile="path/fileName.java" property="version.number"
          encoding="UTF-8">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <!-- equivalent of egrep Version -->
      <containsregex pattern="Version" />
      <!-- equivalent of the cut - extract the bit between the third and
           fourth double quote marks -->
      <containsregex pattern='^[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*"([^"]*)".*$$'
                     replace="\1" />
    </tokenfilter>
    <!-- I'm guessing you don't want a trailing newline on your version num -->
    <striplinebreaks />
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Comment: @jattcoder I've added an alternative suggestion of how you could implement the same logic directly in Ant rather than having to call out to an external process.

Comment: Thanks for your early answer, One more question---
why did you use -d'&quot;'
I just tried 
-d&quot;\&quot;&quot;
in your code and it worked.

Comment: @jattcoder that would work too.  `-d'"'` and `-d"\""` are exactly the same, they both result in `cut` seeing an argument of `-d"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `'` in your xml

```
<exec command='egrep Version ./path/fileName.java | cut -d"\"" -f4)' outputproperty="VER"/>
```